# Hibernate add a book to a user

Tags: java, hibernate

I've made a many to many relation between `User` and `Books`. Now I want to add an existing book to an existing user in `User_Books` but every time I do it also makes a empty new user in the `User` table.

```
       Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
       cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
       SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
       Session session = factory.openSession();
       Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Books book = new Books();
        book.setBookshareId(bookshareId);

        User user1 = new User();
        user1.setUser_id(userID);

        user1.getBooks().add(book);
        session.save(user1);

       tx.commit();
```

**User:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tblUser")
public class User implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name = "Id",unique = true,nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int Id;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="user")  
private List<Books> books = new ArrayList<Books>(); 

public void addBooks(Books book) {
    this.books.add(book);
}
```

**Books:**

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "User_Books",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Books_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "User_id")})
private List<User> user = new ArrayList<User>();

 public void addUser(User user) {
        this.user.add(user);
    }
```

@Mohamed Nabli
when I execute this It finds them but when I look in the User_Books I dont se anything.

```
                  DEBUG Collections - Collection found: [entity.bookdetail.Books.user#946669], was: [entity.bookdetail.Books.user#946669] (uninitialized)
12:00:37 web.1 |  DEBUG Collections - Collection found: [entity.users.User.books#6], was: [entity.users.User.books#6] (uninitialized)
12:00:37 web.1 |  DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 2 objects
12:00:37 web.1 |  DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 1 updates, 0 removals to 2 collections
12:00:37 web.1 |  DEBUG EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
12:00:37 web.1 |  DEBUG EntityPrinter - entity.bookdetail.Books{copyright=1998-01-01 00:00:00.0, images=0, author=J. K. Rowling, briefSynopsis=Second in ...
12:00:37 web.1 |  DEBUG EntityPrinter - entity.users.User{password=u1t1, books=<uninitialized>, Id=6, email=user1@test1.com}
12:00:37 web.1 |  DEBUG JdbcTransaction - committed JDBC Connection
12:00:37 web.1 |  DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl - Releasing JDBC connection
12:00:37 web.1 |  DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl - Released JDBC connection
```

Comment: If the user already exists, why don't you fetch him from the db and then add the book (instead of creating a new User?), the same applies to the book, don't create a new one...

Comment: how do I get an existing user?,I thought that if you .setUser() that you told that you have to had the book to this user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :)

```
Books book = (Books) session.get(Books.class, book_id);
User user =  (User) session.get(User.class, user_id);
List<User> users=book.getUser();
users.add(user);
book.setUser(users);
session.saveOrUpdate(book);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work,

you have the user and the book in your database, dont use new to create a user you will have to fetch it directly from database.

add this line to your ManyToMany annotation for your User Class

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})  
private List<Books> books = new ArrayList<Books>();
```

Try this :

```
Books book = (Books) session.get(Books.class, book_id);
     User user =  (User) session.get(User.class, user_id);
     List<Books> books=user.getBooks();
     books.add(book);
     user.setBooks(books);

    session.saveOrUpdate(user);
```

Comment: when I execute this It finds them but when I look in the User_Books I dont se anything.

Comment: @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "User_Books",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Books_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "User_id")})

Try this Out ...
private List<User> user = new ArrayList<User>();